# Optimize complicated SQL Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, sql-server-2000

Somebody at work made this UPDATE some years ago and itt works, the problem is it's taking almost 5 hours when called multiple times in a process, this is not a regular UPDATE, there is no 1 to 1 record matching between tables, this does an update based on accumulative (SUM) of a parituclar field in the same table, and things get more complicated because this SUM is restricted to special conditions based on dates and another field.

I think this is something like an (implicit) inner join with no 1 to 1 match, like ALL VS ALL, so when having for example 7000 records in the table this thing will process 7000 * 7000 records, more than 55 million, in my opinion cursors should have been used here, but now i need more speed and i don't think cursors will get me there.

My question is: Is there any way to rewrite this and make it faster?? Pay attention to the conditions on that SUM, this is not an easy to see UPDATE (at least for me).

More info:
CodCtaCorriente and CodCtaCorrienteMon are primary keys on this table but, as I said before there is no intention to make a 1 to 1 match here that's why this keys are not used in the query, CodCtaCorrienteMon  is used in conditions but not as a join condition (ON).

```
UPDATE #POS SET SaldoDespuesEvento = 
     (SELECT SUM(Importe) 
        FROM #POS CTACTE2
       WHERE CTACTE2.CodComitente = #POS.CodComitente  
         AND CTACTE2.CodMoneda = #POS.CodMoneda
         AND CTACTE2.EstaAnulado = 0 
         AND (DATEDIFF(day, CTACTE2.FechaLiquidacion, #POS.FechaLiquidacion) > 0 
              OR
             (DATEDIFF(day, CTACTE2.FechaLiquidacion, #POS.FechaLiquidacion) = 0 
              AND (#POS.CodCtaCorrienteMon >= CTACTE2.CodCtaCorrienteMon)))) 
WHERE #POS.EstaAnulado = 0 AND #POS.EsSaldoAnterior = 0
```

[image: ScreenShot - Execution Plan]

Comment: Do you mind giving a picture of the Query Plan?

Comment: What indexes do you have in the table? It would help if you added the `CREATE TABLE` statement as well.

Comment: I tried adding indices for different fields but there is not big change, something interesting: There is a tremendous change (from 3 minutes to 3 seconds in small test) when removing this line in WHERE: #POS.CodCtaCorrienteMon >= CTACTE2.CodCtaCorrienteMon. CodCtaCorrienteMon is a numeric and incremental field, the reason for this condition is not affecting records (don't SUM) when the record in the inner query has this a higher value in this field than the corresponding field in the record in the outer query.

Comment: How many rows does the table have in total and how many are updated (i.e. pass the test `#POS.EstaAnulado = 0 AND #POS.EsSaldoAnterior = 0`)?

Comment: I used 7000 records in my last test (it's not always the same) it depends on how the temp table is created. Almost all rows are updated, that filter won't exlcude many rows.
You know, i'm starting to think there is no better way to do this.

Comment: Found the solution, this is the typical Running Totals problem, there are many questions about this on this site.

Answer (score 1):

From your query plan it looks like its spending most of the time in the filter right after the index spool.

If you are going to run this query a few times, I would create an index on the 'CodComitente', 'CodMoneda', 'EstaAnulado', 'FechaLiquidacion', and 'CodCtaCorrienteMon' columns.

I don't know much about the Index Spool iterator; but basically from what I understand about it, its used as a 'temporary' index created at query time. So if you are running this query multiple times, I would create that index once, then run the query as many times as you need.

Also, I would try creating a variable to store the result of your sum operation, so you can avoid running that as much as possible.

```
DECLARE @sumVal AS INT

SET @sumVal = SELECT SUM(Importe) 
        FROM #POS CTACTE2
       WHERE CTACTE2.CodComitente = #POS.CodComitente  
         AND CTACTE2.CodMoneda = #POS.CodMoneda
         AND CTACTE2.EstaAnulado = 0 
         AND (DATEDIFF(day, CTACTE2.FechaLiquidacion, #POS.FechaLiquidacion) > 0 
              OR
             (DATEDIFF(day, CTACTE2.FechaLiquidacion, #POS.FechaLiquidacion) = 0 
              AND (#POS.CodCtaCorrienteMon >= CTACTE2.CodCtaCorrienteMon)))

UPDATE #POS SET SaldoDespuesEvento = @sumVal
WHERE #POS.EstaAnulado = 0 AND #POS.EsSaldoAnterior = 0
```

Comment: It is a conditional sum, meaning it's not only 1 SUM, there are as many SUM() as rows are in the table, see the dates conditions and CodCtaCorrienteMon condition inside the inner query, they depend on a value on the outer query record. It's not a common update, it works like code inside cursors applying a SUM(), record by record.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to help much without the query plan but I would make the an assumption that if there is not already indexes on the FechaLiquidacion and CodCtaCorrienteMon columns then performance would be improved by creating them as long as database storage space is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, this is a common problem: Running Totals

This is one of the few cases CURSORS perform better, see this and more available solutions here (or browse stackoverflow, there are many cases like this):

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2009/07/28/SQL-Server-2005-Fast-Running-Totals.aspx